how to use localStorage in redux-toolkit with nextJS?
So i have a problem with localStorage and nextJS, and I need SSR to work. Here is the code:
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const initialState = {
    theme:
        typeof window !== "undefined"
            ? localStorage.getItem("theme") || "light"
            : "light"
}

export const themeSlice = createSlice({
    name: "theme",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setTheme: (state, action) => {
            state.theme = action.payload
            if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
                localStorage.setItem("theme", action.payload)
            }
        }
    }
})

export const { setTheme } = themeSlice.actions

export default themeSlice.reducer

So here is breakdown: when user enters the page he just gets light theme but when he clicks to change theme and reloads to page it is expected to remain in dark mode. Unfortunately it does not work with nextJS
also I found some guide about implementing Store into nextJS app and here is my StoreProvider:
"use client"
import { AppStore, makeStore } from "@/lib/store"
import { useRef } from "react"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"

export default function StoreProvider({
    children
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) {
    const storeRef = useRef<AppStore>()
    if (!storeRef.current) {
        storeRef.current = makeStore()
    }

    return <Provider store={storeRef.current}>{children}</Provider>
}

As you can see i have here 'use client' but it does not work as i expected.
layout.tsx:
<html lang="ru">
            <body>
                <AppRouterCacheProvider options={{ enableCssLayer: true }}>
                    <StoreProvider>
                        <MyThemeProvider>
                            <Container>
                                <Header />
                                <main
                                    style={{ marginTop: "40px" }}
                                    // className={montserrat.className}
                                >
                                    {children}
                                </main>
                                <ToastContainer
                                // style={{ marginTop: '50px' }}
                                />
                                <Footer />
                            </Container>
                        </MyThemeProvider>
                    </StoreProvider>
                </AppRouterCacheProvider>
            </body>
        </html>

here is how the theme toggles:
import { Button } from "@mui/material"

import DarkModeOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DarkModeOutlined"
import LightModeOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LightModeOutlined"
import { useAppDispatch } from "@/lib/hooks/useAppDispatch"
import { setTheme } from "@/providers/ThemeProvider/model/reducer/themeSlice"
import { useAppSelector } from "@/lib/hooks/useAppSelector"

const ToggleTheme = () => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
    const theme = useAppSelector(state => state.theme.theme)

    const handleThemeChange = () => {
        dispatch(setTheme(theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark"))
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Button
                onClick={handleThemeChange}
                variant="text"
                sx={{
                    minWidth: 35,
                    backgroundColor: theme === "dark" ? "#111" : "#eee"
                }}
            >
                {theme === "dark" ? (
                    <DarkModeOutlinedIcon sx={{ color: "primary.main" }} />
                ) : (
                    <LightModeOutlinedIcon sx={{ color: "primary.main" }} />
                )}
            </Button>
        </>
    )
}

export default ToggleTheme

store.ts:
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { themeSlice } from "@/providers/ThemeProvider/model/reducer/themeSlice"
import searchSlice from "@/features/SearchPost/model/searchSlice"
import { DigestApi } from "@/widgets/Digest/models/DigestApi"
import categoriesReducer from "@/features/ScrollCategories/model/categoriesSlice"

export const makeStore = () => {
    return configureStore({
        reducer: {
            theme: themeSlice.reducer,
            search: searchSlice.reducer,
            categoryStateSchema: categoriesReducer,
            [DigestApi.reducerPath]: DigestApi.reducer
        },
        middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
            getDefaultMiddleware().concat([DigestApi.middleware])
    })
}

// Infer the type of makeStore
export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>
// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<AppStore["getState"]>
export type AppDispatch = AppStore["dispatch"]

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Does your makeStore() utility check for any previous state in localStorage? Can you [edit] to share a more complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

@DrewReese added more code, hope it is what you asked

Sorry, not quite. I was asking to specifically see your makeStore utility function, imported from import { AppStore, makeStore } from "@/lib/store", so we can see where and how it creates the store object and passes any initial state value.

@DrewReese I provided store.ts file where makeStore comes from

Ok, thanks. You should pass any persisted state from localStorage to configureStore's preloadedState. Obviously this will need to do a check if the code is running in the server or on the client to read from localStorage and pass any initial state.

Even if you get Redux to store its state in local storage, the page will still flicker in light mode before switching to dark mode if that's its default. If you want to keep track of dark mode or a theme on both the server and the client, create a route that modifies a cookie, and set the state based on that variable.

@Andrew so if I want to track theme without flickering from light theme to dark I need to use cookies instead of localStore?

That's right. LocalStorage lives in the browser alone, so when things are server rendered, they will use the default value initially, and then read the localStorage value, and depending on how you handle that, possibly update once they're on the client. Cookies on the other hand follow the user around on both the client and the server, so they can be used as a user configurable variable in both locations on the first rendering pass.
